# Knockout Mapping always returns empty array

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

So here is my code:

```
var myData= @Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyData);
console.log(myData) //log1
var viewModel = { };
viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(myData);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
console.log(viewModel.model); //log2
```

In my console, `log1` will always display the array in the `[Object, Object, Object]` format with the correct data.

However, `log2` is always empty. I am getting no errors or anything. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show a http://jsfiddle.net illustrating your issue?

Comment: You'll have to show us an example of the data that you see. If you are mapping a valid object, it's not just going to return "empty" whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure myData is in the right format for the automapper (namely, a JavaScript object, or JSON). One thing you may want to do is encode it as JSON by doing:

```
var myData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.MyData));
```